# Looping through a group of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to figure out the best way in SQL Server to find some characters in some tables.
Would you advise me which is the best way to loop through a group of tables/columns to find some characters using only SQL commands(stored procedures...)?

Thanks in advance.

Example:

1. Selecting the group of tables/columns:

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name
, c.name AS column_name
--, ty.Name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
where ty.Name = 'uniqueidentifier'
```

2. Output of the select

```
 table_name                 column_name
 formset_details_translation    formset_details_translation_id
 formset_details_translation    formset_version_id
 current_schema_instances       original_unique_guid

...
```

3. Finding loop. How should I use? cursor?

```
for each Table
    For each Column
        select * 
        from tableI
        where columnI = 'XXXX...XXXX'
    End For
End For
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Are you asking how to search a specific text in multiple columns of multiple tables?

Comment: This is usually a sign of a broken data model - often known as attribute splitting. Have you ended up with *data* embedded in your table/column names? Data of the same "kind" ought to be in a single column in a single table.

Comment: I would like dynamically loop through different tables, using like declare t = table_name Select * from t, and then replace t for every table that I want to loop throuh (Sorry by my English language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it something that you are looking at ?

```
DECLARE @cnt INT,@ID int = 1
Declare @TempTable table(ID int IDENTITY(1,1), table_name varchar(200), column_name varchar(200))

Insert into @TempTable
SELECT t.name AS table_name
, c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.user_type_id = ty.user_type_id
where ty.Name = 'uniqueidentifier'

Select @cnt =  count(1) from @TempTable
Declare @sql varchar(max), @table_name varchar(200), @column_name varchar(200) 
WHILE @ID <= @cnt
BEGIN

 SET @sql = ''
 SET @table_name = ''
 SET @column_name = ''
 Select @table_name = table_name,@column_name = column_name from @TempTable where ID = @ID
 SET @sql = 'select * from ' + @table_name + ' where ' + @column_name + ' = 123' --You can replace 123 by your text

 PRINT (@sql) -- You can write EXECUTE (@sql) here to execute it


 SET @ID = @ID + 1
END
```

Comment: So sorry Tirthak, I need more reputation for that (I need 15 points and I have 14)

Answer (score 1):

It requires some manual work, but you could something like this:

```
select
    TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
    cmd = 'select ''' + table_name + ''' as tabname, ''' + column_name + ''' as colname, count(*) as rows from [' + TABLE_CATALOG + '].[' + TABLE_SCHEMA  + '].[' +  TABLE_NAME + '] where [' + COLUMN_NAME + '] like ''%%'' union all '
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where 1=1
    and DATA_TYPE like '%char'
    and TABLE_NAME like '%%'
```

Then you just execute the resulting query (change the select to fit your needs better and remove the last `union all`). 
The results for every column in the same table will be in different rows, but you could use `FOR XML PATH` to generate `OR` statements so it doesn't return same rows duplicated by searched columns.

If you need this to be dynamic, without copying and pasting, check this **undocumented** procedure out:

```
sp_msforeachtable @command1="declare @x Nvarchar(255); set @x='select count(*) from ?'; execute sp_executesql @x"
```

Build your queries in `@command1` using `information_schema.columns`, like in previous example.

Comment: I accepted the Tirthak's answer because I tried to solve my problem with that answer and it worked, but this answer should work too. Thank you for your answer.